# call nested chain based on some condition

Tags: spring-integration

```
<int:chain input-channel="chainB">
    <int:gateway request-channel="chainC" error-channel="errChannel"/>
</int:chain>

<int:chain input-channel="chainC">
     .....
    <int:gateway request-channel="chainD"/>
    .....
`   <int:gateway request-channel="chainE"/>
</int:chain>

<int:chain input-channel="errChannel">
     ......
     <int:gateway request-channel="chainF"/>//this line is conditional
     <service-activator ......     />this line has to be executed everytime
     ......
</int:chain>
```

1) if chainD fails, i dont have to execute chainE. This works fine.

2) Some header "Release" is being set in chainD. I want to call chainF only if the chainD was successfully able to set that header.

***Adding more information -***

1. ChainD sets the header 'Release'
2. ChainE is executed after chainD. I set some header 'ChainERequest' in that.

Now i have 3 schenarios -

1. Chain D is success, Chain E is success
2. Chain D fails, chain E will not be called. So 'Release' might be null or not-null depending on which line chainD failed.
3. Chain D is success, chain E fails. Release is not-null, ChainERequest is not null.

The error flow logic is as follows -

1. Call transformer A
2. Call transformer B
3. If ChainERequest == null && Release != null, then call chainF.  return back
4. call transformer C

How do i write step 3?

Answer (score 1):

You can examine the `failedMessage` property on the payload of the `ErrorMessage`.

If the flow failed after `ChainD`, it will have the header, if it failed before, it won't.

```
<int:filter expression="payload.failedMessage.headers['Release'] != null" />
```

Comment: Thanks Gary. I have to make the flow common after calling chain F. I tried using filter but it requires a discard-channel, however I don't want to discard the message. I have to execute the next line irrespective of whether Release is null or not. Is there any way to return back from filter's discard channel to caller chain.

Comment: Your initial question said you didn't want to call the service if the `Release` header is populated; hence the filter. Confused. Please re-state your question - i.e. __exactly__ what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have added additional information above, can you please guide me on step 3

Comment: Use a [router](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#router). If both headers are set, route to `chainF`, if not route directly to transformer C, skipping chainF.

Comment: it doesn't allows me to specify a router in mid of a chain, router can be specified only as last component. When condition is true I hv to execute two steps - chain and transformer and then return to caller. if condition is false I have to call transformer and return back to caller.

Comment: You'll have to route out of the chain - with the router as the last element.